# How to change time and convert format in python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, datetime

We have converted the format from UTC to Europe/Berlin, but time is unchanged. We're using python and pandas on an ubuntu server.

We have tried to run a code that supposedly should change time as well as the format. Nonetheless, time is the same.

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.read_csv('feeds.csv', date_parser=dateparse)

df['created_at'] = df['created_at'].str.replace(' UTC', '')
df['created_at'] = pd.to_datetime(df['created_at'])
df['created_at'].dt.tz_localize('UTC').dt.tz_convert('Europe/Berlin').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

df.to_csv('feeds.csv',index=False)


print(df)
```

Time should be changed, so that 12:50:13 changes to 14:50:13

[image]

Comment: assign it back `df['created_at']=df['created_at'].dt.tz_localize('UTC').dt.tz_convert('Europe/Berlin').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')`

Comment: Please don't post images of code/data/Tracebacks.  Just copy the text, paste it in your question and format it as code.
[You should not post code as an image because:](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2823755)

Comment: Also see [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](//stackoverflow.com/q/20109391) for very good advice on how to post Pandas questions. We don't need the CSV input, we just need a small dataframe. I created a minimal example in my answer.

Comment: Thanks, but due to time, you have to wait 10 min, @wwii :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the result of your conversion back to the column:

```
df['created_at'] = df['created_at'].dt.tz_localize('UTC').dt.tz_convert('Europe/Berlin').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

You already did so on the preceding two lines.

You can skip the `dt.tz_localize()` call by telling `pd.to_datetime()` to handle this for you:

```
df['created_at'] = pd.to_datetime(df['created_at'], utc=True)
df['created_at'] = df['created_at'].dt.tz_convert('Europe/Berlin').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Finally, just chain all operations into one:

```
df['created_at'] = (
    pd.to_datetime(df['created_at'].str.replace(' UTC', ''), utc=True)
    .dt.tz_convert('Europe/Berlin')
    .dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
)
```

Demo:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"created_at": ["2019-07-26 12:50:13 UTC", "2019-07-26 13:00:13 UTC"]})
>>> df
                created_at
0  2019-07-26 12:50:13 UTC
1  2019-07-26 13:00:13 UTC
>>> df['created_at'] = (
...     pd.to_datetime(df['created_at'].str.replace(' UTC', ''), utc=True)
...     .dt.tz_convert('Europe/Berlin')
...     .dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
... )
>>> df
            created_at
0  2019-07-26 14:50:13
1  2019-07-26 15:00:13
```